# What was the purpose of Abel's family being sent to meet Donovan in Bridge of Spies?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, bridge-of-spies

In *Bridge of Spies,* Jim Donovan meets Rudolf Abel's family in East Berlin.

> They were faking being his family members.

Who was behind these people putting on this act? And what was their purpose in arranging for them to put this act on? Emotional manipulation of Donovan, for some negotiating advantage?

Answer (score 3):

The USSR refused to admit that Abel was a spy, despite the pretty clear evidence. The family was a farcical effort to keep up the fiction that Abel wasn't a spy, even though the USSR knew that the US would see through it.